# Prove that every multiple of six is also a multiple of three

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I am wondering how to approach this, is it enough to say that $x=6y$ where $y \in \Bbb Z$ and then write $x=3(2y)$?

It seems valid and logical but at the same time very short solution. Did I miss something?

All responses are appreciated!

Comment: $x=6*y=3*(2*y)$ Now you can conclude, so I think you pretty much got it

Comment: Yes, what you've said is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. It just boils down to the fact that

$$6\cdot n =(3\cdot 2)\cdot n = 3\cdot(2\cdot n)$$

along with the fact that $2n$ is an integer if $n$ is. This last observation is important, because otherwise you could say something like
$$6\cdot n = 7\cdot(\tfrac67 n)$$ and erroneously conclude that every multiple of $6$ is also a multiple of $7$.

---

**Addendum:** Using the same form of proof, you can easily make the generalization that if $a$ is a multiple of $b$, then $a$ is a multiple of every divisor of $b$.

Comment: i.e. it's an immediate consequence of the **associativity** of the  multiplication operation (on integers).

Comment: @BillDubuque : Quite so. I debated whether or not to mention this in light of the level of the question.